# ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

After spending a day installing docker and compose on Ubuntu, it is still not working.

Now, when trying to run docker-compose I get the following:

```
ERROR: The Docker Engine version is less than the minimum required by Compose. Your current project requires a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0 or greater.
```

**Installed Version**

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Update docker engine to version 1.10.0 or greater ?

Comment: Or downgrade compose if the upgrade is absolutely not possible

Comment: Not a chance. I have wasted so much time trying to get docker and compose correctly installed. This happens everytime I install docker on any machine. I will try find another solution that doesnt involve changing docker installation.

Comment: Maybe you use docker-compose version 2 syntax? It's supported from version 1.10 of docker https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2

Comment: If you installed docker-compose using pip you should be able to just use `pip install -I docker-compose==1.6.2` or `pip uninstall docker-compose && pip install docker-compose==1.6.2` to get a version of compose which supports your docker version. Version 1.7.0 requires docker version 1.10.0 or later: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you need to run that docker version? It is currently 2 versions behind, since 1.11.1 is now out.

If you can't upgrade for some reason, then you will need to downgrade the docker compose version to a version that supports 1.9.1

You can download compose 1.6.2 from here https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.2 which is compatible with docker 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker-machine upgrade default` to upgrade the docker server - you have `1.9.1` which is lower than required by Compose in this case, `1.10.0`.